# How to Set Image on QPushButton on Left hand side in QT?

Tags: qt

How to Set Image on QPushButton on Left hand side in QT ?

I am using below code to set image on button using stylesheet.
But this gives my same images so many times, i want only a single dislpay that too on left of my button.[image]

```
 b1->setStyleSheet(

               "background-image: url(:/user.gif);"
               "border-style: outset;"
               "border-width: 2px;"
               "border-radius: 10px;"
               "border-color: black;"
               "font: bold 16px;"
               "color: black;"
               "min-width: 10em;"
               "min-height: 0.75em;"
               "margin: 0 1px 0 1px;"
               "color:rgb(0,0,0);"
               "padding: 6px;"
               );
```

I solved my issue using :

```
"background-repeat:no-repeat;"                  
               "background-position:left top;"
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept OrcunC's answer by clicking the checkmark next to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `background-repeat no-repeat;` to style sheet.